# Piecewise styling and decoration of a tikz path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

I have this path, which I would like to style "piecewise" from a single specification, shown on the image below:

[image: test06.png]

As the image says, I'd like to decorate segments 2-3 and 5-6, and colorize only 3-4. I'd like to decorate 2-3 with a `snake` (sinusoidal decoration), which implies that the 1-2 segment going upwards should be drawn invisibly (somewhat like a moveto).

The problem, as visible on the image, is that I get absolutely no decorations on the third picture, which means I didn't get the right syntax for piecewise styling and decorations (if it is even possible).

My question is - how could I achieve the kind of decoration I want, but with on a "single line" (with a single coordinates' path specification)? The MWE so far is below:

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} % (solid) snake :)
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % show path construction

\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth

\begin{document}

This is the plain linear path:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[]
  (0,0) -- ++(1,0) node[fill,scale=0.5](A){}
  -- +(0,1) -- +(0,-1) -- ++(1,0)
  -- ++(2,1) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

This is the path construction:

\gdef\cnt{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={show path construction,
  moveto code={
    \fill [red] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) circle (2pt);
  },
  lineto code={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{\cnt+1} \xdef\cnt{\tmp} %
    \ifnum\cnt=2{\gdef\tw{3pt}}\else{\gdef\tw{1pt}}\fi %
    \ifnum\cnt=3{\gdef\tc{blue!50}}\else{\gdef\tc{blue}}\fi %
    \draw [draw=\tc,line width=\tw,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast) node[fill=none,draw=green,minimum size=2pt,font=\bf]{\tmp};
  },
  closepath code={
    %\draw [draw=none] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
  },
},
decorate]
  (0,0) -- ++(1,0) node[fill,scale=0.5](A){}
  -- +(0,1) -- +(0,-1) -- ++(1,0)
  -- ++(2,1) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

Attempt at decorating only segments\\ 2-3 and 5-6, and coloring only 3-4

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[]
  (0,0) -- ++(1,0) node[fill,scale=0.5](A){}
  { [draw=none]-- +(0,1) }
  { [decorate,decoration={snake},draw=red]-- +(0,-1) } % 2-3
  { [draw=green]-- ++(1,0) }
  -- ++(2,1)
  { [decorate,decoration={snake},draw=red]-- ++(0,-1) } %5-6
  -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need a meta-decoration. But is it always the same segments with same decorations?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @percusse - indeed, I forgot to specify: it is not always the same segments, they can change arbitrarily - I may want, in principle, say, `n`th segment, then `n+2`nd and `n+3`rd segment, then finally `n+10`th segment... Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Right, I got to a sort of a partial solution, so I'll post it here... This is the output I get with the MWE posted below:

[image: test02b]

The first thing to remember is, that if you think that braces `{}` have any sort of grouping within a `\draw` path, they do **not**; you can try `[draw=green]{-- ++(1,0)}` or `{ [draw=green]-- ++(1,0)}` - but either the color will be ignored, or it will be applied to the path globally.

Second thing is that there is a sort of a way around this with decorations, but not with meta-decorations. The meta, as the regular ones, are basically intended to repeat patterns along a line (in other words, they repeat states); here I want to apply individual styles to specific (i.e. random) line segments; so the full facility like this of decorations is not applicable to this problem.

What *is* applicable, though, is that there is a `decoration=moveto`, which actually can be used, as is, to "hide" an arbitrary line segment. The problem is, the syntax directly contradicts what I have in my version of the Tikz & PF manual (Manual for Version 2.10):

> Indeed, the following two commands have the same effect:
>   1. \path decorate[ options ] { path };
>   2. \path [decorate, options ] path ;

Well, at least in my version, that is - luckily - incorrect; if you write:

- `decorate[decoration=moveto]{ --  +(0,1) }` - then the decoration will be applied *only* to the line segment inside the braces, which I want
- `[decorate,decoration=moveto]{ --  +(0,1) }` - then either the decoration will be ignored, or will be applied globally

So, at least for hiding, and decorations like `snake` with no other demands, this works. But can we apply individual styling? For the most part, entering color or line width options inside the decoration `[]` options will be ignored (or applied globally).

So, in the code below, there is a custom decoration called `example`. It basically jumps over its `{initial}` state, and it goes in the `{final}` directly. There, first it outputs the path built up to that point using `\pgfusepath` - however, one should take note that `\pgfusepath` *kills* the global path up to that point, so you have to at least manually `moveto` a point, to allow the further path building constructs to work. Then the "current" stroke color is saved, and the new one is read from options set previously (see [Reading - and effect - of (default) tikz/pgf keys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185163/reading-and-effect-of-default-tikz-pgf-keys) to see for pitfalls in understanding how global TikZ option keys may work).

And then set; then the line segment is finished, then `\pgfusepath` is called again so the path is output styled - but this kills the global path again, so again we have to at least move. Then, since we also want to reset back to original color there, we re-set back to the default settings set previously - but again we have to call `\pgfusepath` to set the new color ( `:)` ), and since this destroys the global path, we have to moveto at least once after that. Whew! `:D`

And that finally allows for individual styling of line segments - but it's not perfect; if you specify e.g. `\draw[line width=1pt]`, you'll see it's only applied to the final segments (obviously, because of all of the destruction introduced by `\pgfusepath`).

Here is the code producing the image above:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes} %% nope
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} % (solid) snake :)
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % show path construction

\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth


\makeatletter
\global\let\tmpmc\relax \global\let\tmpcc\relax
\pgfdeclaredecoration{example}{initial}
{
  % {initial} is done for as long
  % as \pgfdecoratedremainingdistance < width;
  % but for 0pt it loops indefinitely!
  % > "First, this option causes an immediate switch
  % > to the state final if the remaining distance
  % > on the input path is less than dimension."
  % When \pgfdecoratedremainingdistance+1pt, indeed
  % it jumps immediately, nothing inside executes;
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance+1pt]
  {
    % this will never print
    \typeout{decoration{example} INITIAL} %
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    % example for printing coordinates of point:
    % (note, here \pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast
    %  is same as \pgfpointdecoratedpathlast)
    \pgfpointdecoratedpathlast    % first go here, at this point
    \pgfgetlastxy{\dcplx}{\dcply} % grab coords in macros
    \typeout{dcpl \dcplx, \dcply} % print coords to stdout
    %
    % NOTE:
    % > "\pgfusepath{ actions } Applies the given
    % > actions  to the current path. Afterwards,
    % > the current path is (globally) empty."
    % print all the path, up to now, with default (black) color
    \pgfusepath{draw,stroke} %
    %
    % remember the current (old), set the new color
    \makeatletter %
    \typeout{\string\color@pgf@tempcolor,           % \color@pgf@tempcolor,
      \csname\string\color@pgf@tempcolor\endcsname} % 0 g 0 G
    \extractcolorspec{pgf@tempcolor}{\tmpc} %
    \extractcolorspecs{pgf@tempcolor}{\tmpmc}{\tmpcc} %
    \typeout{tmpc \tmpc}                  % tmpc {gray}{0}
    \typeout{tmpmc \tmpmc, tmpcc \tmpcc}  % tmpmc gray, tmpcc 0
    \makeatother %
    % get the new color from previously set key:
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/draw}{\tmpdraw} %
    \typeout{tmpI \tmpdraw} % tmpI green
    % finally, set new color as stroke color
    % (green!50 works here; note black!0 is transparent!)
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\tmpdraw} %
    %
    % since now after \pgfusepath, the global path is dead/cleaned;
    % have to reinitialize the global path first by a moveto
    % (else the lineto after, doesn't know what to lineto from)
    % happily, here the coord system is local to the segment,
    % so 0.0pt refers to the first point of the segment
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast} %
    %
    % must usepath again, to output stroked
    \pgfusepath{draw,stroke} %
    %
    % now global path is dead again - so move to the
    % end point; but we'll have to reset the color...
    %\color[gray]{0.5}  % this resets the stroke color to default,
                        % but does not set it! ok syntax, complains
                        % if range not [0,1]
    %\colorlet{tmpold}[gray]{0.5} % no can do
    %\definecolor{tmpold}{gray}{0.5} % ok
    \definecolor{tmpold}{\tmpmc}{\tmpcc} %
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{tmpold} %
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    % moveto is enough here, no need for \pgfpathlineto
    % must usepath again, to output stroked
    % (print all up to now with black)
    \pgfusepath{draw,stroke} %
    %
    % now global path is dead again - move to the end
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    % now further subpaths can continue to
    % append to the last point here...
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is the plain linear path:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[]
  (0,0) -- ++(1,0) node[fill,scale=0.5](A){}
  -- +(0,1) -- +(0,-1) -- ++(1,0)
  -- ++(2,1) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1,0);
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/color}{\tmp}\typeout{tmpX \tmp \meaning\tmp}
\end{tikzpicture}

This is the path construction:

\gdef\cnt{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={show path construction,
  moveto code={
    \fill [red] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) circle (2pt);
  },
  lineto code={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{\cnt+1} \xdef\cnt{\tmp} %
    \ifnum\cnt=2{\gdef\tw{3pt}}\else{\gdef\tw{1pt}}\fi %
    \ifnum\cnt=3{\gdef\tc{blue!50}}\else{\gdef\tc{blue}}\fi %
    \draw [draw=\tc,line width=\tw,->] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast) node[fill=none,draw=green,minimum size=2pt,font=\bf]{\tmp};
  },
  closepath code={
    %\draw [draw=none] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
  },
},
decorate]
  (0,0) -- ++(1,0) node[fill,scale=0.5](A){}
  -- +(0,1) -- +(0,-1) -- ++(1,0)
  -- ++(2,1) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

Attempt at decorating only segments\\ 2-3 and 5-6, and coloring only 3-4

% \edef\dcA{decorate[decoration={lineto,},green]} % color no effect here
\def\dcA{decorate[decoration={example,/tikz/draw/.initial=green,},every path/.append style={line width=1pt}]} % color ok, line width no effect here

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1pt]
  % start here:
        (0,0)
  % (default) line to here:
                                    -- ++(1,0)
  % place node:
        node[fill,scale=0.5](A){}
  % line, but hidden (moveto):
       decorate[decoration=moveto]{ --  +(0,1) }
  % only this segment, decorate snake:
     decorate[decoration={snake,}]{ --  +(0,-1) } % 2-3
  % only this segment, decorate example (green):
                              \dcA{ -- ++(1,0) }
  % (default) line to here:
                                    -- ++(2,1)
  % only this segment, decorate snake:
  % [decorate,decoration={snake},red] out here
  %  would be applied globally! (but only from
  %  the end of example decoration)
  % with decorate[decoration={snake},red],
  %  the red is ignored.
  decorate[decoration={snake},red]{ -- ++(0,-1) } %5-6
  % (default) line to here:
                                    -- ++(1,0)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```